# Add parameters dynamically

Tags: python

Is there a way to add parameters dynamically when calling a function? For example:

```
def getParameters(num):
    parray = [i for i in range(num)]
    params = tuple(parray)
    return params

def func(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Each time, when calling the function `func`, the number of parameters is decided by the function `getParameters`, which is unknown until the code is executed.

For example, in the code, someone may do this:

```
param1 = getParameters(2)
# they wants to use param1 to the func
# which would be func(1, 2)

param2 = getParameters(6)
# Likewise, this would be func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

But I can't directly pass the tuple to the function, Python would treat it as a single parameter in that way.

Since the `*args` is a tuple, which contains those extra parameters, is there a way to replace `*args` with `param1`
(also, the same thing to `**kwargs`)?

Comment: Why would `getParameters(2)` produce 4 parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unpack a tuple of positional arguments and/or a dictionary of keyword arguments to a function, use the same syntax, using asterisks:

```
def show_args(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)

show_args(*(1, 2, 3), **{4: True, 5: False})
```

In your case, it would be

```
func(*param1)
```

However, note that your `getParameters` doesn't actually `return` anything.

Comment: A downside to unpacking arguments is that you lose safety checks against mistakes when calling the function, such as the wrong keyword argument or the wrong number of positional arguments. Without unpacking, those mistakes raise a `TypeError`. With unpacking, any unused arguments are just discarded.